# MSI GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4g - converter

Tags: hdmi, dvi, adapter

I recently assembled a PC. After I finished my build, I turned it on, but there was nothing on screen, just a black screen.

If I test my PC with a borrowed HDMI monitor it works.

I only have a VGA monitor, so I had to use a DVI to VGA adapter to connect the graphics output.

My question is: I used this adapter in a lot of old graphics cards and never had this problem until now. I'm asking if the problem is that, this specific graphics card needs necessarily an active adapter or if it doesn't really support any kind of adapters?

My second question: Besides connecting directly via HDMI to a monitor (which means I have to buy a new monitor), if I can't get a HDMI monitor, is it better to use the HDMI TO VGA or DVI TO VGA adapter.

Specs:

- Mobo: MSI B250M Mortar
- CPU: I5-7400 6MB 3.0GHz LGA1151
- GPU: MSI GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GB OC
- RAM: Hyper Fury 1x8GB DDR4 2133MHz
- PSU: Corsair cx430W
- OS: Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Please go through your question and correct the grammatical and spelling mistakes, there are far to many issues to fix it myself, since th resulting edit would significantly changed what you have said.  *I will be unable to answer your question unless I can actually understand it.*

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using a *VGA to DVI-I* adapter?

Comment: Your question is harder to read because you used so much bold.  I also have no idea what you mean by the words "noite" and "Aldo".

Comment: While you have recieved an answer.  You should continue to improve your question, because poorly worded questions, are unlikely to be well recieved by the community.  As I said I would fix the problems, but there are far to many to fix, and the resulting changed I would have submitted would have changed the meaning of your words to drastically.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, i'm extremely sorry about my gramatical errors and "unknowned words", since i'm Portuguese and i'm using my Smartphone, some words were corrected by my keyboard to portuguese words. About the "poorly worded questions", that is actually my fault. Thank you for your advice and sorry, i will try my best to improve.

Comment: Bad english is one thing. It is not my native language either. It did make the question a lot harder to understand though. However once you know the PC worked with a different cable and monitor you could have trimmed a lot of irrelevant text.

Comment: @HePy - In the future don't use a smartphone to submit your questions.  I have submitted entire answers, from my smartphone, without any formatting issues though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using a VGA monitor, so i had to use a DVI to VGA adaptor to
>   connect to the GPU.

You are using a DVI-I to VGA adapter.  The `MSI GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4g OC` has a DVI-D port.  A DVI-I (digital and analog) converter is not compatible with the DVI-D (digital only) connector on your GPU.  VGA is an analog only signal, your current DVI-I to VGA adapter can only convert the DVI analog signal to a VGA signal.

### Video Output Function

> - DisplayPort x 1
> - HDMI x 1
> - Dual-link DVI-D x 1

Specifications: [MSI GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4g OC](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-card/GeForce-GTX-1050-Ti-4G-OC.html#hero-overview)

> i used this adapter in a lot of old GPUs and never had this problem
>   but now, so i'm asking if the problem is that, this especific GPU
>   needs necessarily an active adapter or if it doesn't really support
>   any kind of adapters.

In your previous use cases your GPU had a DVI-I port, which is easily converted to VGA, which si the reason your passive DVI-I to VGA adapter worked.  DVI-D is a digital only signal, which requires an active converter, in order to convert it to a analog siganl like VGA.  Your current adapter does not have this capability.

> is it better to use the HDMI TO VGA or DVI TO VGA adapter.

You can do either one just make sure you purchase a DVI-D to VGA converter if you don't select the other option.  Active DVI to VGA adapters typically have the following limitations.

[image]

Comment: Hardware recomendatons are not on topic here at Superuser.  So I will be able to suggest anything specific.  I also will be unable to indicate which solution is better, either solution will work, so I am going to leave that decision in your capable hands

Comment: New monitor is 10x the cost of a $15 adapter though